# Parse List Of Objects To Newtonsoft.Json JArray In C#

Tags: c#

How can I parse a List to JArray using Newtonsoft.Json in C#?

```
List<Person> people=new List<Person>();
JArray result = JArray.FromObject(people);
```

FromObject threw an error,
so I thought it was because it converts only objects
and not lists,
but the error was due to another problem,
and FromObject work great!!!

Comment: Parsing means converting a string into objects. You're asking how to transform one set of objects into another

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can test `JArray.FromObject(people)` (see [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_FromObject.htm))

Comment: OK so update your question with what you've tried to do with `FromObject`, the error message, what the `Person` class looks like, etc.

Comment: The error was from a another problem; Now it works! Thanks for the help!